# Артефакты при использовании MFT h.264 энкодера в WebRTC

Tags: c++, windows, видео, webrtc, windows-media-foundation

Возникла проблема при использовании Microsoft h.264 Encoder внутри WebRTC. Спустя какое-то время после начала трансляции (Desktop App <-> browser) на стороне браузера (Chrome 71) возникают артефакты:
[image: corruptimage]

Было замечено что при этом входящий битрейт падает до примерно 30kb/s (при среднем около 0.5Mb/s) и заметно уменьшается кол-во приходящих в секунду пакетов:[image: graphs]

При написании честно подсматривал код использования энкодера openh264 из WebRTC:

> modules\video_coding\codecs\h264\h264_encoder_impl.cc

WebRTC используется собранное из 68 ветки.

Ниже пойдёт код энкодера.
Создание медиатипов для трансформы:

```
HRESULT createMediaTypes(CComPtr<IMFMediaType> &inputType, CComPtr<IMFMediaType> &outType)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // input type

    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&inputType);

    hr = inputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    hr = inputType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_NV12);
    hr = MFSetAttributeSize(inputType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, _opts.width, _opts.height);
    hr = inputType->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, (UINT64)_opts.fps << 32 | 1);
    hr = inputType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlaceMode::MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);

    // output type

    hr = MFCreateMediaType(&outType);

    hr = outType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    hr = outType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
    hr = outType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, _opts.bitrate);
    hr = outType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_MPEG2_PROFILE, eAVEncH264VProfile_Main);
    hr = MFSetAttributeSize(outType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, _opts.width, _opts.height);
    hr = outType->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, (UINT64)_opts.fps << 32 | 1);
    hr = outType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlaceMode::MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);

    return S_OK;
}
```

Создание объекта MFT и выставление параметров через CodecAPI:

```
HRESULT createEncoder(IMFMediaType* inType, IMFMediaType* outType, int32_t coresNum)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CMSH264EncoderMFT), nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&_encoder));

    hr = _encoder->SetOutputType(0, outType, 0);
    hr = _encoder->SetInputType(0, inType, 0);

    hr = _encoder->QueryInterface(IID_ICodecAPI, (void**)&_codecApi);

    hr = setCodecApiBool(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVLowLatencyMode, true);
    hr = setCodecApiUint(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncNumWorkerThreads, coresNum);
    hr = setCodecApiUint(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed, 0); // Does not help
    hr = setCodecApiUint(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize, _opts.gopSize);
    hr = setCodecApiUint(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncMPVDefaultBPictureCount, 0);
    hr = setCodecApiUint(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, eAVEncCommonRateControlMode_PeakConstrainedVBR);
    hr = setCodecApiUint(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncCommonMaxBitRate, _opts.bitrate);

    hr = _encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_FLUSH, 0);
    hr = _encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_START_OF_STREAM, 0);
    hr = _encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING, 0);

    return S_OK;
}
```

Инициализация энкодера (метод WebRTC):

```
int32_t InitEncode(const webrtc::VideoCodec* codecSettings, int32_t coresNumber, size_t maxPayloadSize)
{
    if (!codecSettings || codecSettings->codecType != webrtc::kVideoCodecH264)
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_ERR_PARAMETER;

    if (codecSettings->maxFramerate == 0)
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_ERR_PARAMETER;

    if (codecSettings->width < 1 || codecSettings->height < 1)
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_ERR_PARAMETER;

    if (FAILED(MFStartup(MF_VERSION)))
    {
        RTC_LOG(LS_ERROR) << "MFStartup Failed";
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_ERROR;
    }

    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> inputType = nullptr;
    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> outputType = nullptr;

    _opts.coresNumber = coresNumber;
    _opts.fps = codecSettings->maxFramerate;
    _opts.gopSize = codecSettings->H264().keyFrameInterval;
    _opts.height = codecSettings->height;
    _opts.width = codecSettings->width;
    _opts.payloadSize = maxPayloadSize;

    if (codecSettings->targetBitrate < codecSettings->startBitrate)
        _opts.bitrate = codecSettings->startBitrate;
    else if (codecSettings->targetBitrate > codecSettings->maxBitrate)
        _opts.bitrate = codecSettings->maxBitrate;
    else _opts.bitrate = codecSettings->targetBitrate;

    _opts.bitrate *= 1000; // in bps

    RTC_LOG(LS_WARNING) << "Bitrate init:" << _opts.bitrate;

    _durationInMfTime = 10'000'000 / codecSettings->maxFramerate;

    auto hr = createMediaTypes(inputType, outputType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_ERROR;

    hr = createEncoder(inputType, outputType, coresNumber);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_ERR_PARAMETER;

    // Initialize encoded image. Default buffer size: size of unencoded data.
    _encodedImage._size = codecSettings->width * codecSettings->height * 3 / 2;
    _encodedImage._buffer = new byte[_encodedImage._size];
    _encodedImage._completeFrame = true;
    _encodedImage._encodedWidth = 0;
    _encodedImage._encodedHeight = 0;
    _encodedImage._length = 0;

    return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_OK;
}
```

Очистка энкодера (метод WebRTC):

```
int32_t Release()
{
    if (_encoder)
    {
        _encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_END_OF_STREAM, NULL);
        _encoder->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_COMMAND_DRAIN, NULL);
    }

    _codecApi.Release();
    _encoder.Release();

    delete[] _encodedImage._buffer;

    if (FAILED(MFShutdown()))
    {
        RTC_LOG(LS_ERROR) << "MFStartup Failed";
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_ERROR;
    }

    return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_OK;
}
```

И самое интересное - сам энкодинг (метод WebRTC):

```
int32_t Encode(const webrtc::VideoFrame& frame, const webrtc::CodecSpecificInfo* csi, const std::vector<webrtc::FrameType>* frameTypes)
{
    if (_encodedCallback == nullptr)
    {
        RTC_LOG(LS_WARNING)
            << "InitEncode() has been called, but a callback function "
            << "has not been set with RegisterEncodeCompleteCallback()";
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_UNINITIALIZED;
    }

    if (_encoder == nullptr)
    {
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_UNINITIALIZED;
    }

    auto forceKeyFrame = false;
    if (frameTypes != nullptr)
    {
        // We only support a single stream.
        RTC_DCHECK_EQ(frameTypes->size(), 1);
        // Skip frame?
        if ((*frameTypes)[0] == webrtc::kEmptyFrame)
        {
            return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_OK;
        }

        // Force key frame?
        forceKeyFrame = (*frameTypes)[0] == webrtc::kVideoFrameKey;
    }

    auto buffer = frame.video_frame_buffer()->ToI420();

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    auto width = frame.width();
    auto height = frame.height();

    auto ySize = width * height;

    auto dataY = buffer->DataY();
    auto dataU = buffer->DataU();
    auto dataV = buffer->DataV();

    auto strideY = buffer->StrideY();
    auto strideU = buffer->StrideU();
    auto strideV = buffer->StrideV();

    CComPtr<IMFSample> nv12Sample = nullptr;
    hr = createMediaSample(ySize * 3 / 2, &nv12Sample);

    CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> nv12Buffer = nullptr;
    hr = nv12Sample->GetBufferByIndex(0, &nv12Buffer);

    byte* data = nullptr;

    hr = nv12Buffer->Lock(&data, nullptr, nullptr);

    auto r = libyuv::I420ToNV12(
        dataY, strideY,
        dataU, strideU,
        dataV, strideV,
        data, width,
        data + ySize, width,
        width, height);

    hr = nv12Buffer->Unlock();

    hr = nv12Sample->SetSampleTime(frame.timestamp() / 100); // mf time units in 100 ns
    hr = nv12Sample->SetSampleDuration(_durationInMfTime);

    if (forceKeyFrame)
    {
        // must set before input
        setCodecApiUintIfSupported(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncVideoForceKeyFrame, TRUE);
    }

    hr = transformProcessInput(_encoder, 0, nv12Sample);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        TimestampRec rec;
        rec.timestamp = frame.timestamp();
        rec.ntp_time_ms = frame.ntp_time_ms();
        rec.render_time_ms = frame.render_time_ms();

        _timestamps[frame.timestamp() / 100] = rec;
    }

    CComPtr<IMFSample> h264Frame = nullptr;

    while (true)
    {
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr = transformProcessOutput(_encoder, 0, h264Frame)))
        {
            LONGLONG timestamp;
            hr = h264Frame->GetSampleTime(&timestamp);

            TimestampRec rec;
            auto founded = _timestamps.find(timestamp);
            if (founded != _timestamps.end())
            {
                rec = founded->second;
                _timestamps.erase(timestamp);
            }
            else continue;

            UINT32 picType;
            h264Frame->GetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_VideoEncodePictureType, &picType);

            CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> mediaBuffer = nullptr;
            h264Frame->GetBufferByIndex(0, &mediaBuffer);

            _encodedImage._encodedWidth = width;
            _encodedImage._encodedHeight = height;
            _encodedImage._timeStamp = rec.timestamp;
            _encodedImage.ntp_time_ms_ = rec.ntp_time_ms;
            _encodedImage.capture_time_ms_ = rec.render_time_ms;
            _encodedImage.rotation_ = frame.rotation();
            _encodedImage.content_type_ = webrtc::VideoContentType::UNSPECIFIED;
            _encodedImage.timing_.flags = webrtc::TimingFrameFlags::kInvalid;
            _encodedImage._frameType = picType == eAVEncH264PictureType_IDR ? webrtc::kVideoFrameKey : webrtc::kVideoFrameDelta;

            byte* data = nullptr;
            DWORD size = 0;
            mediaBuffer->Lock(&data, nullptr, &size);
            _encodedImage._length = size;

            memcpy(_encodedImage._buffer, data, _encodedImage._length);

            mediaBuffer->Unlock();

            if (size)
            {
                UINT64 sampleQp;
                h264Frame->GetUINT64(MFSampleExtension_VideoEncodeQP, &sampleQp);
                _encodedImage.qp_ = sampleQp;

                auto nalUnits = ReadH264Frame(_encodedImage._buffer, size);

                webrtc::RTPFragmentationHeader header;
                header.VerifyAndAllocateFragmentationHeader(nalUnits.size());

                for (size_t i = 0; i < nalUnits.size(); i++)
                {
                    auto nalUnit = nalUnits[i];
                    header.fragmentationOffset[i] = nalUnit->offset;
                    header.fragmentationLength[i] = nalUnit->length;
                }

                // Deliver encoded image.
                webrtc::CodecSpecificInfo codecSpecific;
                codecSpecific.codecType = webrtc::kVideoCodecH264;
                codecSpecific.codecSpecific.H264.packetization_mode = webrtc::H264PacketizationMode::NonInterleaved;

                auto result = _encodedCallback->OnEncodedImage(_encodedImage, &codecSpecific, &header);
                _encodedImage._length = 0;
            }

            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_OK;
}
```

При обновлении параметров кодирования WebRTC вызывает метод:

```
int32_t SetRateAllocation(const webrtc::VideoBitrateAllocation& allocation, uint32_t framerate)
{
    auto sumBps = allocation.get_sum_bps();

    if (sumBps <= 0 || framerate <= 0)
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_ERR_PARAMETER;

    _opts.bitrate = sumBps;
    _opts.fps = framerate;

    _durationInMfTime = 10'000'000 / framerate;

    if (FAILED(updateParams()))
        return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_ERROR;

    return WEBRTC_VIDEO_CODEC_OK;
}
```

Где параметры к MFT применяются так:

```
HRESULT updateParams()
{
    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> inType = nullptr;
    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> outType = nullptr;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // codecapi
    hr = setCodecApiUintIfSupported(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncCommonMaxBitRate, _opts.bitrate);

    // out type
    hr = _encoder->GetOutputCurrentType(0, &outType);
    hr = outType->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, (UINT64)_opts.fps << 32 | 1);
    hr = outType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, _opts.bitrate);
    hr = _encoder->SetOutputType(0, outType, 0);

    // in type
    hr = _encoder->GetInputCurrentType(0, &inType);

    hr = inType->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, (UINT64)_opts.fps << 32 | 1);

    hr = _encoder->SetInputType(0, inType, 0);

    return S_OK;
}
```

Собственно, вопросы: почему возникают просадки битрейта с артефактами, почему просадки именно до 30 kb/s и что делать чтобы всё это исправить? Или куда смотреть/что читать.

Всем спасибо.

Comment: Ну во-первых WebRTC обычно передает медиа по UDP и пакеты могут теряться. Во-вторых непонятно, чем занимается ваш энкодер во время таких лагов и почему там почти нигде не проверяется возвращаемые hr.

Comment: Что пакеты могут теряться - это понятно конечно. Но тестирование проходит или на одной машине или в одной сети, так что не должны. Плюс ко всему, кодеки vp8, vp9 и имплементация h264 через кодек openh264 работает отлично, проблема именно в этой реализации. Ещё сюда же - когда начинаются лаги с артефактами, метод Encode просто не вызывается. А hr проверяется, просто вырезано чтобы кода было меньше для вопроса =)

Comment: А почему он не вызывается? Зачем было его приводить, если он не вызывается?

Comment: Метод обычно вызывается, в нём идёт конвертирование картинки из I420 в h264. Если бы метод вообще не вызывался, то на принимающей стороне в браузере не было бы никакого изображения. Вызовы перестают приходить когда начинаются лаги.

Comment: Скорее наоборот, лаги начинаются, когда он перестает вызываться. Вот я и спрашиваю, отчего он перестает вызыватьсяя.

Comment: Возможно что так. Но почему не вызывается мне и самому интересно, на моей стороне локов не замечено. Метод Encode вызывается WebRTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось. Проблема была в том, что в энкодер подавалась неправильная временная отметка. Время *webrtc::VideoFrame::timestamp()* считается в юнитах с частотой 90 кГц, а не в наносекундах, как предполагалось. После приведения времени к юнитам MFT в 100 нс, артефакты пропали.

Изменения в методе *Encode*. Было:

```
hr = nv12Sample->SetSampleTime(frame.timestamp() / 100); // mf time units in 100 ns
hr = nv12Sample->SetSampleDuration(_durationInMfTime);

if (forceKeyFrame)
{
    // must set before input
    setCodecApiUintIfSupported(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncVideoForceKeyFrame, TRUE);
}

hr = transformProcessInput(_encoder, 0, nv12Sample);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    TimestampRec rec;
    rec.timestamp = frame.timestamp();
    rec.ntp_time_ms = frame.ntp_time_ms();
    rec.render_time_ms = frame.render_time_ms();

    _timestamps[frame.timestamp() / 100] = rec;
}
```

Стало:

```
auto timestampMf = frame.timestamp_us() * 10;

hr = nv12Sample->SetSampleTime(timestampMf); // mf time units in 100 ns
hr = nv12Sample->SetSampleDuration(_durationInMfTime);

if (forceKeyFrame)
{
    // must set before input
    setCodecApiUintIfSupported(_codecApi, &CODECAPI_AVEncVideoForceKeyFrame, TRUE);
}

hr = transformProcessInput(_encoder, 0, nv12Sample);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    TimestampRec rec;
    rec.timestamp = frame.timestamp();
    rec.ntp_time_ms = frame.ntp_time_ms();
    rec.render_time_ms = frame.render_time_ms();

    _timestamps[timestampMf] = rec;
}
```